# Regular expression to match top n occurences of words

Tags: regex

I have a string in format:

```
word<class> word<class>...
For example:
I<Noun> like<verb> to<Function> eat<verb>...
```

Is it possible to use regex to find top n words that occur for each class, for example top 4 noun words using regular expression. It will output the list of words.

Thanks

Comment: How is the regex supposed to know a word is a noun? Sometimes, it's not obvious to a _human_.

Comment: well, you want to list out proper nouns?

Comment: You don't even tell what the language is

Comment: You're going to have to write a program to do this. Regular expressions may form part of your solution, but they are not the answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression cannot be used for counting.

So no -- you cannot find top n words using regexps.

Comment: If you force it to, it can do. Of course, the performance would suffer - badly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish what you are doing you need to use parts of speech tagger to classify what sort of words are used in the sentence.
You can use any one of natural language processing libraries to do that.
For eg. in python you have pynltk.
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1091-how-to-use-an-nltk-part-of-speech-tagger/

After that you need group the words according to the parts of speech and count them.
So totally out of scope for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern is `(\\s|^)([a-zA-Z]+?)<Noun>(\\s|$)`, in every found match you should use `$2` to get the result

In c# you can achieve this by using following code:

```
     string type = "Noun";
     int top = 5;

     MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches("I<Noun> like<verb> to<Function> eat<verb> an apple<Noun>", String.Format("(\\s|^)([a-zA-Z]+?)<{0}>(\\s|$)", type));

     List<string> res = new List<string>();

     for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count && i < top; i++)
     {
        res.Add(mc[i].Result("$2"));
     }
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im oops, I was subscribed to c# before and just now added regex to subscriptions, didn't notice, that there is no c# tag. but regex pattern should work anyway